# Best strategy for error handling in an interface to a database and web display

Tags: python, database, database-design, pyramid

I decided to ask this question after going back and forth 100s of times trying to place error handling routines to optimize data integrity while also taking into account speed and efficiency (and wasting 100s of hours in the process. So here's the setup.

```
Database  ->  python classes  ->   python code     ->   javascript
 MongoDB  |   that represent  |   that serves      |  web interface
                the data         pages (pyramid)
```

I want data to be robust, that is the number one requirement. So right now I validate data on the javascript side of the page, but also validate in the python classes which more or so represent data structures. While most server routines run through python classes, sometimes that feel inefficient given that it have to pass through different levels of error checking.

**EDIT: I guess I should clarify. I am not looking to unify validation of client and server side code. Sorry for the bad write-up. I'm looking more to figure out where the server side validation should be done. Should it be in the direct interface to the database, or in the web server code where the data is received.**

**for instance, if I have an object with a barcode, should I validate the barcode in the code that reviews the data through AJAX or should I just call the object's `class` and validate there?**

**Again, is there sort of guidelines on how to do error checking in general? I want to be sort of professional, and learn but hopefully not have to go through a whole book.**

I am not a software engineer, but I hope those of you who are familiar with complex projects, can tell me where I can find few guidelines on how to model/error check in a situation like this.

I'm not necessarily looking for an answer, but more like pointing me to a short set of guidelines when creating projects with different layers like this. Hopefully not extremely long..

I don't even know what tags to use in the post. HELP!!

Answer (score 2):

Validating on the client and validating on the server serve different purposes entirely. Validating on the *server* is to make sure your model invariants hold and has to be done to maintain data integrity. Validating on the *client* is so the user has a friendly error message telling him that his input would've validated data integrity instead of having a traceback blow up into his face.

So there's a subtle difference in that when validating on the server you only really care *whether or not* the data is valid. On the client you also care, on a finer-grained level, *why* the input could be invalid. (Another thing that has to be handled at the client is an input format error, i.e. entering characters where a number is expected.)

It is possible to meet in the middle a little. If your model validity constraints are specified declaratively, you can use that metadata to generate *some* of the client validations, but they're not really sufficient. A good example would be user registration. Commonly you want two password fields, and you want the input in both to match, but the model will only contain one attribute for the password. You might also want to check the password complexity, but it's not necessarily a domain model invariant. (That is, your application will function correctly even if users have weak passwords, and the password complexity policy can change over time without the data integrity breaking.)

Another problem specific to client-side validation is that you often need to express a dependency between the validation checks. I.e. you have a required field that's a number that must be lower than `100`. You need to validate that a) the field has a value; b) that the field value is a valid integer; and c) the field value is lower than `100`. If any of these checks fails, you want to avoid displaying unnecessary error messages for further checks in the sequence in order to tell the user what his specific mistake was. The model doesn't need to care about that distinction. (Aside: this is where some frameworks fail miserably - either JSF or Spring MVC or either of them first attempts to do data-type conversion from the input strings to the form object properties, and if that fails, they cannot perform any further validations.)

**In conclusion**, the above implies that if you care about data integrity, *and* usability, you necessarily have to validate data at least twice, since the validations achieve different purposes even if there's some overlap. Client-side validation will have more checks and more finer-grained checks than the model-layer validation. I wouldn't really try to unify them except where your chosen framework makes it easy. (I don't know about Pyramid - Django makes these concerns separate in that `Form`s are a different layer than your `Model`s, both can be validated, and they're joined by `ModelForm`s that let you add additional validations to the ones performed by the model.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm more of looking for guide on server side validation though. Sorry.

Comment: @xcorat I just realised I phrased things terribly. (It was 2am in the morning when I wrote the anserr.) "Client-side validation" should be "the validation done in the user interface". This can obviously be performed server-side by the web framework. By "server-side validation" I meant "the validation done when model entities are saved or updated" - which is not necessarily a consequence of direct user input, but can be a side-effect of an operation.

Comment: @xcorat I guess better names would be "view-layer validation" and "model-layer validation". If you're at all familiar with Django, the former is done by `Form`s, and the latter is done by `Model`s. Even if you're not familiar you might want to poke at how they implement this because it's a design I think is fundamentally correct, and you might want to steal some ideas for your work, or it might help you better understand the components that do this in Pyramid. (Which as I understand it is more modular and disjointed.)

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look. And yeah I don't know what they are, but i'm sure I can find out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your question, but error handling on pymongo can be found here -

- http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/errors.html

Not sure if you're using a particular ORM - the docs have links to what's available, and these individually have their own best usages:

- http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tools.html

Do you have a particular ORM that you're using, or implementing your own through pymongo?